# Proof of $a^{2^p}=x^pax^{-p}=a$ $\forall a \in G$

Tags: group-theory

I have to complete this exercise:

"Let $G$ be a group with an element of finite order $n>1$ and exactly two conjugacy classes. Prove that $|G|=2$"

The author gives some  hints:

" Prove the existence of a prime $p$ such that $a^p = 1 \ \forall a \in G$,

if $p$ is odd and $a \in G$, then exists an element $x$ s. t. $a^2= xax^{-1}$,

So $a^{2^p}=x^pax^{-p}=a$ and this is a contradiction of Fermat's theorem."

I proved the existence of the prime $p$ but I don't know how to demonstrate that $\forall a \in G$  $$a^{2^p}=x^pax^{-p}$$ I need only to prove this to finish the exercise because all the rest is done. I thought that $a^{2^p}=a^{2 \cdot 2^{p-1}}=(a^2)^{2^{p-1}}=xa^{2^{p-1}}x^{-1}$ but this lead to nothing and in every other case I tried, $x$ appears only with exponent $1,-1$. 
thanks in advance :)
the exercise is from "Rotman's An Introduction to the theory of groups" p.45 n $3.4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a^2=xax^{-1}\to (xax^{-1})^2=a^4\to xa^2x^{-1}=a^4\to x(xax^{-1})x^{-1}=a^{2^2}\to \cdots$$

Comment: Perfect, didn't thought about this sequence. :):) Thanks

Comment: @RicPed: What I could get from your question is to find the relation. Is it enough? If it does'n satisfy , tell me tor remove that.

Comment: No no it's exactly what I need to complete the exercise :)

Comment: Using your proof I can find an absurd so $p$ must be 2, therefore my group is abelian and so it has 2 elements :)